# Stop parent (subprocess.Process) from propagating signal to children (multiprocessing.Process) in Windows

Tags: python-3.x, windows, subprocess, python-multiprocessing

Parent process (`subprocess.Process`) creates some children with `multiprocessing.Process`. And if parent receives *SIGINT/SIGBREAK* it's also propagated to the children processes.

If the children were also constructed using `subprocess.Process`, I would use

```
    creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP
```

and they would be created in a new process group. But so far, in my findings, I think we cannot create process groups in `multiprocessing`. (please correct me, if I'm wrong)

Question:
How can we can stop propagating the signal to the children (`multithreading.Process`)?

The expected result; only parent receives the signal, and it's children don't.

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Your assumption that the event is 'propagating' is wrong. If the user types Ctrl+C or Ctrl+Break while the console is doing a processed (not raw) read,  the console host (conhost.exe) has the session server (csrss.exe) inject a thread in each attached client process, pretty much simultaneously, that starts at the known `CtrlRoutine` function, which takes the event as its single argument (e.g. `CTRL_C_EVENT` or `CTRL_BREAK_EVENT`). The same applies with `GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent` if the target console process group is 0.

Comment: Are you looking for the worker process to persist even if the console is closed? That will be hard to implement without either monkeypatching multiprocessing or temporarily redirecting the standard handles to NUL and having the child call `FreeConsole`. Otherwise you can simply use ctypes to set a handler that ignores Ctrl+C and Ctrl+Break in each worker process. In this case, since the worker will still be attached to the console, it will be sent `CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT` when the console is closed, which unavoidably terminates the client process within 5 seconds.

Comment: @eryksun So, does this mean that each process starts with a separate process group. Because, I witnessed otherwise. Also, I thought of the same solution (monkeypatching). But the problem is; the worker still needs to be able to catch and handle the signal later.

Comment: Propagating would imply the event gets forwarded from the parent process to its children. But a new thread is created in each process that's attached to the console pretty much simultaneously. When the user presses Ctrl+C or Ctrl+Break in a processed read, or closes the console, the event is sent to all processes attached to the console. It's not filtered by process group. Only `GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent` filters by group.

Comment: Which event does it need to handle 'later'? `CTRL_C_EVENT` and `CTRL_BREAK_EVENT`, or just `CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT`? Your worker can use ctypes to call `SetConsoleCtrlHandler`. Your handler can completely bypass the CRT handler and all of the faked signal handling (Windows doesn't have signals). This is really the only way to handle `CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT` in Python, to shutdown cleanly within the 5 second window the session server gives you.

Comment: worker needs to handle *CTRL_BREAK_EVENT*. I think, [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19901493/how-to-detect-program-exited-in-python-on-windows-and-do-something-on-exit] is an example of what you suggested. I think I get the point. Appreciate the help.

Comment: Using your own console control handler on the injected thread also bypasses Python's restriction to only handle signals in the main thread, which is dysfunctional in Windows. The main thread is often blocked waiting on I/O or an event. Python has an event for `SIGINT` that gets set by its C signal handler in Windows, and in some cases this event gets included in a wait, but not in many cases (e.g. joining a thread from the main thread cannot be interrupted by `SIGINT`). The `SIGINT` event isn't set for `SIGBREAK`, so it's even worse if you try to use a Python `SIGBREAK` handler.

Comment: If I understand correctly, a *SIGBREAK* handler wouldn't be able to cater to SIGINT event. That means, we cannot (**or should not?**) handle *SIGBREAK* in the worker? But, then in windows we cannot also handle SIGTERM. So, how should we signal the worker, then?

Comment: To signal the worker using a console event, and ensure that it gets handled immediately, you need to use `CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP` when creating the process (i.e. monkeypatch multiprocessing) and signal it by sending `CTRL_BREAK_EVENT` to the group ID (i.e. the process ID of the worker). Send the event via `GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent(CTRL_BREAK_EVENT, group_id)` or `os.kill(group_id, CTRL_BREAK_EVENT)`. The worker needs to set a console control handler via `SetConsoleCtrlHandler`, which can use a ctypes callback function.

Comment: If you need non-console or cross-platform support, I suggest using a multiprocessing synchronization primitive instead. For example, have a thread in the worker process wait on a multiprocessing `Event`.

Comment: Since, the worker is a ```multiprocessing.Process```, I cannot use the ```CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP``` attribute. However, the IPC via ```multiprocessing.Event``` is a nice suggestions. I'll certainly try it.

Comment: As I said, using `CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP` would require you to monkeypatch multiprocessing. I think the `creationflags` option of `Popen` should be exposed  in `Process`. It's too important to ignore. It's required in more cases than this, and multiprocessing ties our hands here.

Comment: I thought the same; multiprocessing should have ```creationflags``` attribute, otherwise there's only hack-y workarounds. I think I have enough information to continue exploring from here. Really appreciate the help. Thanks.